# CAN communication in dsPIC33CK64MP508

Tags: pic, brushless-dc-motor, can, logic-analyzer

I tried to transmit data using CAN communication in dsPIC33CK64MP508. I use MCC for configuring CAN in dsPIC33CK64MP508. I set the bit rate to 500 kbps. I just transmit two data bytes (0x41 and 0x42) and I used a logic analyzer to view the data but it shows the error.
I'm using an MCP2551 CAN transceiver.

I have attached my output data using a logic analyzer. Can anyone please correct me?

```c
int main(void)
{
    // initialize the device
    CAN_MSG_OBJ msg;
    uint8_t data[2] = {0x41,0x42};
    SYSTEM_Initialize();
    CAN1_OperationModeSet(CAN_CONFIGURATION_MODE);
    if(CAN_CONFIGURATION_MODE == CAN1_OperationModeGet())
    {
        if(CAN_OP_MODE_REQUEST_SUCCESS == CAN1_OperationModeSet(CAN_NORMAL_2_0_MODE))
        {
            msg.msgId = 0x1FFFF;
            msg.field.formatType = CAN_2_0_FORMAT;
            msg.field.brs = CAN_NON_BRS_MODE;
            msg.field.frameType = CAN_FRAME_DATA;
            msg.field.idType = CAN_FRAME_EXT;
            msg.field.dlc = 2;
            msg.data = data;
            
            if(CAN1_IsBusOff() == false)
            {
                if(CAN_TX_FIFO_AVAILABLE == (CAN1_TransmitFIFOStatusGet(CAN1_TX_FIFO1) & CAN_TX_FIFO_AVAILABLE))
                {
                    CAN1_Transmit(CAN1_TX_FIFO1, &msg);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while (1)
    {
        // Add your application code
    }
    return 1; 
}
```

Output data (Logic analyzer - bit rate: 500000)

[image]

Comment: If you don't have any other device connected to the CAN bus you will typically get an erratic behavior, as the CAN controller is dependent on someone ACK'ing every packet sent else it will re-transmit every packet until it eventually shuts down due to bus error.